# Android string.xml color

Tags: android, xml, string, colors

Color specified as

```
<font fgcolor="#ffff0000">red</font>
```

works, while

```
<font fgcolor="#0000FF">blue</font>
```

does not work.

How fix this problem?

Comment: ... try `<font fgcolor="#ff0000ff">blue</font>`

Comment: work, thank you! And how to make the green color?

Comment: see my answer and read documentation about how colors are defined too

Comment: Marcin Orlowski, thank you!

Comment: ... try `<font fgcolor="#ff00ff00">green</font>` The **rule** is: `<font fgcolor="#aarrggbb">color</font>`. The meaning of the Alpha component is well explained in @MarcinOrlowski's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Android color is defined as `ARGB` where `A` stands for `alpha channel` (transparency). For alpha, value of `00` means fully transparent, and `FF` means fully opaque. So when you define your color as `RGB`, ommiting `A` part, then `A` is being considered as set to `00` which in result makes your color fully transparent, thus your color is `invisible` and may look like `not working`. This behaviour sometimes can differ and lack of of `A` can be interpreted as opaque, but this is rather exception so it's safer to always specify alpha value. BTW: color cannot **work** anyway :)